# Component state not updating from trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs, refluxjs

I'm trying to update the state data in my page component, the callbacks are firing and the correct data is going into each page but the edited value doesn't show in my table component, it shows in the editable input but not in my table cell, the value before it was edited, is displayed instead.

Can anyone please help me get the new value in the page displaying?

I'm using tabs to switch from page to page, each page component is mounted on the main edit page like so:

```
 switch(name) {
        case "PageName":
            return <ExamplePageComponent
                    Id={this.state.id} 
                    sectionData={this.state.studentData.sectionData} />;
```

Each PageComponent editable table has the update method passed into it:

```
var ExamplePageComponent= React.createClass({

onTableUpdate: function(data){
    var resultData = {};
    resultData.studentId = this.props.studentId;
    resultData.sectionId = 11; // section id (listed at parent node (EditStudentPage))
    resultData.elementId = data.elementId;
    resultData.actionType = data.type;
    resultData.data = data;
    resultData.updatedElements = data.updatedElements;
    StudentDataActions.updateStudentData(resultData);
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <Table {...tableOptions} tableData={this.props.sectionData} />
    );
}
});
```

On each tab select I call this method to update the content for each tab page:

```
handleTabSelect: function(key) {
    this.setState({activeTabId: key});
    StudentDataActions.updateEditStudentPageState(this.state.studentId,key);
},
```

Tabs component:

```
<Tabs activeKey={this.state.activeTabId}  onSelect={this.handleTabSelect}>
                    {this.state.sections.map(function(section,i){
                        return (
                            <Tab
                                eventKey={section.value}
                                title={section.label}
                                key={i}
                                tabClassName="tabs__item"
                            >
                                {this.getElementByKey(section.name)}
                            </Tab>
                        );
                    }, this)}
                </Tabs>
```

The handleTabSelect references this action:

```
   updateEditStudentPageState: function(studentID, dataSectionID) {
    this.studentData.dataSectionID = dataSectionID;
    switch(filtersData.dataSectionID){
         case 1:
            Service.loadMethod(filtersData, this.setLoadedState);
//etc
```

On each page component update I call this action/ store method, the saveMethod has the correct data in the callback.

```
updateStudentData: function(addUpdateData) {
    switch(this.data.dataSectionID){
        case 1:
            var callback = function(){
                StudentDataActions.updateEditStudentPageState(rowDataToSave.studentId, 1)
            }.bind(this);
            Service.saveMethod(rowDataToSave, callback);
            break;
        case 2// etc
```

My callback for the above method is:

```
setLoadedState: function(data) {

    this.studentData.activeData.sectionName = data;
    this.trigger(this.studentData);
},
```

My actions are:

```
var ApplicationActions = Reflux.createActions([
'routeChange',
'getPageData',
'setLoadedState',
'updatePageDataFilters'
]);
```

I have used this as an example, https://ochronus.com/react-reflux-example/

Comment: Are you using text/jsx as the script type?

Comment: There may be something amiss inside your `handleTabSelect`: you do a `setState` first, and then fire an action to update some store. `setState` is an async operation, so the call immediately after may not know yet about the new state. In general, such double firing of renders by setState followed by action cycles is always tricky.

Comment: Many thanks for your replies, is there a better way I can structure `handleTabSelect`  to avoid such problems?